# How much time passes between a touch on the screen and my app getting the TouchEvent

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, delay, latency

I'm making an app that needs to log Touch events,(i.e. a user touches a certain place on the screen and I need to log how much time it took since the last time he touched the screen).

I'm using `CACurrentMediaTime` and `CFTimeInterval` to log the time and the delay is microseconds `0.000001`, but I also read that there is a lag between the user touches the screen and my app getting the event?

I read here : http://appglimpse.com/blog/touchmarks-i-smart-phone-touch-screen-latencies/ that the iPhone 5 delay is around `72ms` and the iPhone 4 is `92ms` but is this consistent? if not how does anyone know the range it can be?

I need to know how much milliseconds I need to remove from the final time I log, More precisely I want to know if that number is constant (i.e. 25ms) or does it have a big range (20~80 ms).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be any practical way to know or measure touch lag outside of a lab.

However, if you are only interested in the time between touches we don't need to account for the lag at all if we can assume it is fairly constant. This is because both touches will include the lag.

Here is a mathematical proof of what I'm going on about, assuming lag is constant:

```
time1 = t1 + lag
time2 = t2 + lag

//duration between two touches is time2 - time1
duration = t2 + lag - (t1 + lag)
duration = t2 + lag - t1 - lag
duration = t2 - t1
```

The lag term disappears as both time events are lagged by the same amount.

Comment: I know that if lag is constant I don't need to account for it. However my question is whatever or not it is constant. I assume it has a certain range (i.e. 40~50 ms) and then I have to account for it.

Comment: The only way you will be able to measure touch lag is from a system outside of the iPhone. You won't be able to do it in software on the device.

Comment: I don't need to measure it each time. My question is if the lag is consistent (i.e. 50ms) or has a big range (20~80 ms)

Comment: Ah ok. Then I recommend the question be changed to reflect this. Even if there is a range you still won't be able to account for it though.